# Android Task Implication

Tags: android, android-activity, task

I have read 4 type of activity's launch mode(standard, singleTop, singleTask, singleInstance), and I could imagine how activity will "stacked" depend on its launch mode. 
But what's the implication of starting new activity in new stack vs current stack?

e.g. : 
I start with opening Activity A, then I want to open Activity B, then I have a choice to put this on top of A(Current Stack) or I could start a new Task for this Activity B(as root activity of the new task). What's the implication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you meant "Task" instead of Stack in your sentences.

The first obvious implication is that you'll see a new Task appearing in the Task manager and you'll be able to switch between the new task and the old one. The two will exist in parallel.

Comment: yes, I mean task's activity stack, by "task manager" do you mean recent application(when home button is long pressed)? I have tried using singleInstance in my Activity B, but it's still showed as one app in recent app list..

Comment: SingleInstance does not create a new task. It's a way to prevent creating a new Task when the Activity already exists in an running Task. You should probably never use this flag, as the documentation says. To create a new task you must add the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK when creating the Intent. It's implicit in some cases, like when you launch an Intent from a widget or a Service.

Comment: I still not get it, I have tried with this: Act. A have a button to start Act. B through an intent(with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), the i click the button and i tried to dumpsys through adb. It still show only one taskRecord of my apps, with 2 activityrecord inside it, did i miss something here?

Comment: My previous comment was wrong, singleInstance does indeed create a new task for the Activity implicitly, and prevents any other Activity to be added to that task afterwards. Anyway, the way tasks are displayed to the user in a task manager also depends on the launcher that is used and the Android version. The only thing that you should know is that a task is like an independent workflow with a back stack, that could be brought back to the user to replace the current workflow. The docs explain it better than me: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise until now that on API 21 android display separate task in recent application(google name it Overview Screen). So in pre-API21 there's no significant difference at all?

Comment: In pre api 21 you may not see the tasks but they are there. Like I said, the system may bring back a previously launched task, depending on the launch mode of the Activities it contains.

Answer (score 1):

The implication is that you see both tasks in recents, like having two instances of the app opened.